# Pyspark column population with computation

Tags: r, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I am stuck up with this issue , below is my dataframe

```
a   b   c

0   0   126

30  0   0
```

Now I need to repopulate with column c with formula c(previous-a+b) that is the resulting dataframe should be as . From below dataframe 96 is populated as (126-30+0)

```
a b c

0 0 126

30 0 96
```

Please help me in crossing this hurdle

Comment: Dear Shankar, I tried with lag but I am getting null values for b c column

Comment: I have updated the answer can you check ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lag function to get the previous value as below

```
df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id()) 
  .withColumn("c", lag($"c", 1, 126).over(Window.orderBy("id")) - $"a" + $"b") 
  .drop("id").show(false)
```

Hope this helps!